# audio not working on debian stretch

Tags: debian, audio

I'm running debian stretch on sony VPCSA36GG and the audio **mostly** doesnt work. It would randomly start working on restarting the laptop (its rare tho). Note that I had the same problem when I has windows 10 on the system. Other details :

> abhishek1994@abhishek1994:~$ lspci | grep Audio
>
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

So far I've tried using "alsamixer" in cmdl, that didnt help, plugging in external speakers/headphones doesnt help either. Nor do bluetooth headphones.

I have also installed pulseaudio. The following command returns nothing.

> pulseaudio --log-target-syslog

more info

> abhishek1994@abhishek1994:~$ lsmod | grep snd
>
> snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
>
> snd_hda_intel          36864  2
>
> snd_hda_codec         135168  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
>
> snd_hda_core           86016  3
>
> snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
>
> snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
>
> snd_pcm               110592  4
>
> snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
>
> snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
>
> snd                    86016  10
>
> snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm
>
> soundcore              16384  1 snd